# Changing Django admin template

Tags: django, templates, admin

I follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eosXCVcgtPw&ab_channel=VeryAcademy) to change the Django admin templates, but it seems like the change doesn't go through. I am only changing "Welcome, username" to "Bello, username" to see if it works. Any suggestion?
[admin site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlwdL.png)
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUA29.png)

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```